# Hide comments section

Tags: feature-request, comment, answers

I want to bring up [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/hide-comments-to-view-the-question) discussion again with a possible solution, since nothing has happenend since July. If a 'hide comments'-button is not available, it would be pretty nice to have the answer box above the comment section to see the original post.

What do you think?

Thank you!

Comment: If you've found the duplicate already, please don't ask another copy of it: it is best to keep discussion on one thread. Instead you can try to bump the discussion somehow: I've done it for you by adding some more reasonable tags to the other discussion just now.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you! :-)